# How to set custom 'User-Agent` header in oauth access_token request

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, reddit

I'm developing a spring boot application and am trying to integrate with Reddit oauth using Spring Security. It all works great up until the request to Reddit for the access token.

Reddit has a set of [rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules) that rate limits requests from `User-Agent` including `Java`. The default `User-Agent` sent by java application is `Java/<version>`. I tried overriding this by setting the `http.agent` system property, but `Java/<version>` is still appended to the end [(as shown here)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) which triggers the rate-limiting.

Is there some other simple way I can override the `User-Agent` header that's included in the access token request to the oauth server?

Comment: What HTTP client framework do you use? I understand that your client is a Java application not a browser.